# New Column With Default Value not setting for old records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I created a new Column S_TEST and set its default value to 2 and save the table, but unfortunately the old records were not set automatically, instead they have NULL values. See my screenshots.

[image: Setting up the default value]

[image: Tried to query]

Comment: then you may just run an update query UPDATE table SET S_TEST = 2 WHERE S_TEST IS NULL

Comment: But in our main server db, it's automatically setting the default value for old records and not necessarily to do an update query. I don't know why in my local db, the behavior is not like the server db. @ZHui

Comment: My observation: When I tried to create a new column in between two existing columns, the default value for that new column is set for old records, but if I add a new column to the last existing column and set its default value then the existing rows were not set, instead they have NULL values. I think this is a bug in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: That's because when you insert a column in between existing ones, SQL drops and recreates the whole table. When you insert a column at the end, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @theBenB, I thought it was a bug in SQL Server.

Answer (score 10):

If you add a new column which is **not null** then the default constraint will automatically populate the column with the default value for existing rows.

If you add a new column which is **nullable** the DDL statement should have `WITH VALUES` option to force setting of the default values for existing rows.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tab ADD Col int NULL DEFAULT 10 WITH VALUES ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this way, DBs add new columns with NULL values, even it has a default assigned.
To avoid that, make it not **NULL**:

This works for me on SQL 2016:

```
ALTER TABLE [DB].[MY_TABLE] ADD MyText VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes'
```

Another way of reaching the same, is creating a VIEW on the top of our table.